# Weird error thrown by cv2.fitLine() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I'm using the cv2.fitLine method to find a line segment among many points.

I have the following error:

**error: /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/linefit.cpp:603: error: (-215) npoints2 >= 0 || npoints3 >= 0 in function fitLine**

Here's the section of my code which produces the problem:

```
left_points = [...]
[vxl, vyl, xl, yl] = cv2.fitLine(np.array(left_points, dtype=np.int32), cv2.DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01)
```

The `left_points` array is an array of 2D coordinates, like this:

[(365, 635), (377, 623), (459, 571), (471, 560), (394, 627), (400, 621), (469, 563), (475, 557)]

By the way, I found the original code files of opencv which produces the error: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/linefit.cpp

But it still doesn't explain what I should do. Please help me understand what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: with left_points= the array you posted, I get not error (didn't check if it gives a good result though, but runs with no error).
Is left_points exactly the array you posted ?

Comment: @Soltius no, it's not exactly that but is _supposed_ to have that format. I later checked that in that particular image frame, this array turns out to be empty. I think that was causing the problem - but I got it fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Print your array of points and make sure it's Nx2. What you posted in your message is a list of tuples, not a numpy array.